# i am have error with fopen and other

Tags: c

i don't know what to do, i'am try 10 minutes to fix it, but nothing. 
  i'am a beginner... so... don't dislike somfthing.
  Please help me with code :D
  i working with C one month and it is cool language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *pf;
    char input[500];
    char ime[500];
    int ime2;

    for(ime2 = 0; ime2 >= 9999999; ime2++);

/*

ime2 is: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12... 9999999

*/

    pf = fopen("bruteforce.txt","w");

    if(pf == NULL){
        printf("Datoteka (.txt) po imenu: bruteforce nije pronadjena!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Sledeci text ce biti unesen: \n");
        gets(input);
        ime = input + ime2; // error
        fputs(ime, pf);
        printf("Uspesno je ispisano.\n");
        fclose(pf);
    }

    system("pause >nul");   
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `input` is a string, `ime2` is integer. You can't add string with integer.

Comment: Who thought you `gets()` didn't they know about `fgets()`?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @EugeneSh. you can, what happens because of that is bad. And in other languages for example **javascript** the integer would be concatenated to the string, so the OP might think that the same is going to happen here.

Comment: @iharob For a beginner, it's better to think just that "you can't". Really.

Comment: What's up with the empty for-loop?

Comment: BTW, `for(ime2 = 0; ime2 >= 9999999; ime2++);` should be `for(ime2 = 0; ime2 <= 9999999; ime2++);`. You are using `>=` instead of `<=`.

Comment: @RSahu I think the OP knows that, no matter how wierd it is. I spent around 10 seconds staring at it...

Comment: `input + ime2` produces an address, no?

Comment: @FiddlingBits It is producing a number, which you can interpret as you wish.

Comment: 10 minutes.  You're  complaining about spending 10 mins on debugging?  I don't want to unnecessarily put you off, but that's, like, nothing in software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **change**

```
gets(input)`
```

to

```
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)
```

and then try this

```
snprintf(ime, sizeof(ime), "%s %d", input, ime2);
```

BTW: maybe `MSVC` will not like `snprintf()` as is, they just add an underscore like this

```
_snprintf(ime, sizeof(ime), "%s %d", input, ime2);
```

Comment: Not only `gets()` is insecure, `_snprintf()` is too as it doesn't guarantee null-termination.

Comment: @cremno true, but you can check the return value, and be sure, with `gets()` there is no way to prevent the disaster.